# How can I navigate from one page to another in React-Native? I try to use navigation, but I get the error: Invalid hook call

Tags: typescript, react-native, navigation

I have a class which renders a button which should redirect me to another page. Can I use a navigator created by using useNavigation() inside render() as I did? I don't think so, because I tried this way and it didn't work. Can you please tell me how can I solve this?
When I tried to use it by transforming the class in a functional component, I managed to make it work. But I would like to do the same inside my class.

```
export class PetList extends Component<any, any> {

    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {pets:[]};
    }
 
    render() {
        let navigation = useNavigation();
        return (
            <View style={styles.bigContainer}>
                <Card containerStyle={styles.container}>
                    <Card containerStyle={styles.container}>
                        <Card.Title style={styles.title}> MY PETS</Card.Title>
                        <Card.Divider/>
                        {
                            this.state.pets.map((u:any, i:any) => {
                                return (
                                    <Card key={i} containerStyle={styles.container}>
                                        <View style={styles.pet}>
                                            <Image
                                                style={styles.image}
                                                resizeMode="cover"
                                                source={require('../photos/' + String(3) + '.jpg' )}
                                                alt="Pet photo"
                                            />
                                            <View style={styles.text}>
                                                <Text style={styles.name}>{u.name} </Text>
                                                <Text style={styles.description}>{u.description} </Text>
                                            </View>
                                        </View>
                                    </Card>
                                );
                            })
                        }
                    </Card>
                    <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('addPetForm')}>+</Button>
                </Card>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React native passes the navigator as a prop if it is properly set up. Assuming you made it work using functional component, you should be able to extract the navigation prop by the `{navigation} = this.props` syntax.